# Access Slim Framework 4 as Subfolder

Tags: slim

I am trying to build an api with SLIM Framework V4.

**htdocs/slim/public/index.php**

```
    <?php 

    require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

    use DI\Container;
    use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
    use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
    use App\Middlewares\RequestUser;
    use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
    use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;

    // Create Container using PHP-DI
    $container = new Container();

    // Set container to create App with on AppFactory
    AppFactory::setContainer($container);

    $app = AppFactory::create();

    $app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
        return $response;
    });


    $app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {

        $data = array('message' => 'Unauthorized access');
    $payload = json_encode($data);

    $response->getBody()->write($payload);
    return $response
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->withStatus(201);
    });


    $app->run();
```

If i run php server, it works fine

```
  G:\xampp\htdocs\slim\public> php -S localhost:8888
    PHP 7.2.27 Development Server started at Sun Apr 19 18:42:11 2020
    Listening on http://localhost:8888
    Document root is G:\xampp\htdocs\slim\public
```

If i run

```
http://localhost/slim/public/
```

I am getting

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Slim\Exception\HttpMethodNotAllowedException: Method not allowed. Must be one of: OPTIONS in G:\xampp\htdocs\slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php:96 Stack trace: #0 G:\xampp\htdocs\slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Routing\RouteRunner.php(72): Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->performRouting(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #1 G:\xampp\htdocs\slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(81): Slim\Routing\RouteRunner->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #2 G:\xampp\htdocs\slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(211): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #3 G:\xampp\htdocs\slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(195): Slim\App->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #4 G:\xampp\htdocs\slim\public\index.php(37): Slim\App->run() #5 {main} thrown in G:\xampp\htdocs\slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php on line 96
```

**htdocs**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I am working on windows 10, xampp v3.2.4

The production will be go daddy shared hosting, as a subfolder. I tested it as a subdomain on godaddy server it is working fine. But i need it to be a sub folder of main domain, as godaddy is charging SSL certificate for subdomain too.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: adding $app->setBasePath("/slim-folder/public/index.php"); solved the issue on godaddy server.

Comment: The `public/` directory and `index.php` should not be part of the basePath. Try [this](https://github.com/selective-php/basepath#installation).